# Can I assign a virtual interface (VPN) to a 'real' interface / NIC of my choice?

Tags: vpn, routing, nic, tunneling, interface

I have a small server , running MINT linux with two NICS (eth0 and eth1) and I'd like to setup the MintBox as a VPN client to connect to a web-hosted VPN server.

All works wonderfully on the VPN connectivity front but I'd like to know how to 'force' the VPN to bind/assign itself to eth1, not eth0 (or any NIC of my choice).

I know that OpenVPN creates a virtual interface (tun0) but how does it 'know' which real interface to bind to / forward traffic to?

Have I understood this correctly - and if so , how is this accomplished please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for this options:

--local host
    Local host name or IP address. If specified, OpenVPN will bind to this address only. If unspecified, OpenVPN will bind to all interfaces.

bye